# XML, JAXB многие-ко-многим на JAVA

Tags: java, xml, java-ee, xmlparser

Всем привет. Есть вот такой XML:

```
<root>
   <user name="u1">
        <garage>
            <car model="..."/>
            <car model="..."/>
            <bike model="..."/>
        </garage>
        <repairs>
            <car model="..."/>
            <car model="..."/>
            <bike model="..."/>
        </copy>
    </user>
   <user name="u2">
        <garage>
            <car model="..."/>
            <bike model="..."/>
        </garage>
        <repairs>
            <car model="..."/>
        </copy>
    </user>
</root>
```

**как по ПРАВИЛЬНОМУ** будет организовать эту схему на сущностях через JAXB (XML-не модифицировать). Меня интересует связь garage->(car, bike), repairs->(car, bike)
У меня есть вариант, без модификации XML:

```
class Garage{
    List<Car> cars;
    List<Bike> bikes;
}

class Repairs{
    List<Car> cars;
    List<Bike> bikes;
}

class User{
    Garage garage;
    Repairs repair;
}
```

Но, задается мне, такое решение - не корректным ...

Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: В чем конкретно ваша проблема? что у вас не работает?

Comment: Проблем нет - все работает. Вопрос в том, что: "правильно ли я организовал связи для garage->(car, bike), repairs->(car, bike) в сущностях (в коде) для данного XML?"

Comment: если работает и все ваши нужды удовлетворяет и без багов, то все правильно

Comment: Отлично. спасибо!!!